# Search property from nested list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to search an item from nested list. I've to find an item from multiple list. Here's the code example that I've tried. But it's not working. I can't identify where's the problem.

```
 void searchPeople(String query) {

    final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
    final peopleList = _peopleList.where((catDesc) {
      final subCategoryLower = catDesc.subCategoryList!.where((subCatDesc) {
        final pp = subCatDesc.defList!.where((element) {
          return element.defCode!.toString().contains(searchLower) || element.defDesc!.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower);
        }).toList();

        return subCatDesc.subCategoryCode!.toString().contains(searchLower) || subCatDesc.subCategoryDesc!.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower);
      }).toList();

      return catDesc.categoryDesc!.toString().contains(searchLower) || catDesc.categoryCode!.toString().contains(searchLower);
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      this.query = query;
      this._peopleList= peopleList ;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Add all the custom data types also.

Comment: Ankit, here all the code are in and desc are string type

Comment: And what about _peopleList ? Is this List<String>?

Comment: ``List<People>`` inside it ``List<subCategory>`` then ``List<def>``. top list is people. people contains subCategory list and subCategory containse def list

Comment: Thats what I want you to update here, if you could add all these custom data types here then it would be easy to examine your code.

Comment: ```[{
"categoryCode":10,
"categoryDesc":"Documents",
"subCategoryList":
 [{
 "subCategoryCode":1,
 "subCategoryDesc":"Not Found",
 "deficiencyList":
 [{
 "defCode":2,
 "defDesc":"Submitted",
 }```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 void searchPeople(String query) {

   int i=-1,j=-1;

    final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
    final peopleList = _peopleList.where((catDesc) {

      final subCategoryLower = catDesc.subCategoryList!.where((subCatDesc) {


        final pp = subCatDesc.defList!.where((element) {
          return element.defCode!.toString().contains(searchLower) || element.defDesc!.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower);
        }).toList();

        j++;//j only for inner loop
        return pp[j].subCategoryCode!.toString().contains(searchLower) || pp[j].subCategoryDesc!.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower);
      }).toList();

      i++;//i only for outer loop
      return subCategoryLower[i].categoryDesc!.toString().contains(searchLower) || subCategoryLower[i].categoryCode!.toString().contains(searchLower);
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      this.query = query;
      this._peopleList= peopleList ;
    });
  }
```

NOTE:
I thing the idea of using a nested search as in your problem is not a good way because, since `where` will run for every element and so, each time it will create a new list(inner filter logic) which will result in higher time complexity of the logic. A better option is to filter sequentially.